# ReferenceInput is not filing the select component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In React-admin  i am trying to implement a referenceinput. I see that the list api call is made and response is availble. however the selectinput component remains empty.
I would appreciate any help.
Table source column is **notes**. and reference resource is **notes**:

```
<Create actions={<CoaActions />}  title="New Coa" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm variant="standard">
        <TextInput source="code" />
        <TextInput multiline source="title" />
        <TextInput source="iscashbook" />
        <TextInput source="isbankbook" />
        <ReferenceInput label="Notes" source="notes" resource="notes" reference="notes/list">
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <TextInput source="obal" />
        <BooleanInput  source="active" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Removing resource doesnt help unfortunately. funny thing is if i load the data seperately via useQueryWithStore and feed it via choices, It works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the resource prop from the referenceinput